# Not able to create a file using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes

I recently started working on microservices. I am building my docker image and want to deploy it on kubernetes. while creating a pod.yaml file I started getting the below error.

Command :

```
kubectl create -f podservice.yaml
```

Error :

```
error: the path "podcpeservice.yml" does not exist
```

Tried using the helpfor kubectl create -f help. An example in the help document is

command :

```
kubectl create -f ./pod.json
```

Even the above command gives the same error. Not able to figure out what is the problem. tried removing `./`

I am using centos 7 on virtual-box with windows 7 as host.

Comment: Can you run an `ls` in your working directory and show us the output, just in case?

Comment: docker-registry initial-setup-ks.cfg mydockerfiles mykubernetes

Comment: In that case the error seems obvious. You don't have the file that you're trying to use! `kubectl create -f file.yaml` assumes that `file.yaml` is in the current directory.

Comment: you maybe misunderstood the purpose of `kubectl create -f`: it will create a kubernetes resource (Deployment, Service, ...), which you first have to specify in a file with the given name. It does not create that file for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tushar,

First you need to create the deployment yml file using one of the editor, then pass the file as argument for kubectl command.

eg.

kubernets team already created this deployment file. you use kubectl to deploy.

```
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/controllers/nginx-deployment.yaml
```

Comment: link is dead by the way. i've failed to find something similar on this site in adjacent categories

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the filename was corrupted with unseen symbol so this helped me to get over wrong naming

```
mv postgres-configmap.yaml\  postgres-configmap.yaml
```

and then it worked:

```
kubectl create -f postgres-configmap.yaml
configmap/postgres-config created
```