# AZ CLI/kubectl apply error - - the path does not exist

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, kubernetes

I'm working through a tutorial on Kubernetes on Azure tutorial ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-deploy-application)) and everything has worked perfectly until I run the `kubectl apply` to configure the cluster:

```
bash-4.4# kubectl apply -f azure-vote-all-in-one-redis.yaml

error: the path "azure-vote-all-in-one-redis.yaml" does not exist
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45056575/not-able-to-create-a-file-using-kubectl) question which is right on point if I were trying to use a URL for the file.

I've tried:

```
kubectl apply -f azure-vote-all-in-one-redis.yaml

and

kubectl apply -f /Users/bill/Documents/GitHub/azure-voting-app-redis/azure-vote-all-in-one-redis.yaml
```

The `kubectl` command is run from the AZ CLI (I'm using VSCode - with everything configured for Azure and Docker - no problems seeing anything).

if I `ls` from the AZ CLI I get:

```
bash-4.4# ls
azure-cli  dev        home       media      proc       run        srv        tmp        var
bin        etc        lib        mnt        root       sbin       sys        usr
bash-4.4#
```

I've also looked through the docs for `AZ CLI` and `kubectl` and every indication is that it should simply work.  I also tried `kubectl` from the `console` which obviously didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, most command like this, when you execute the command with an argument file, you should in the same directory which the file in or with an absolute path of the file.

So you can use two ways to execute the command:

First, you can go into the directory which the file azure-vote-all-in-one-redis.yaml in and then execute the command `kubectl apply -f azure-vote-all-in-one-redis.yaml`.

Second, you can use an absolute path. How to get the path? You can go into the directory and execute the command `pwd`. Or you can use the command `whereis azure-vote-all-in-one-redis.yaml` to get the path.

**Update**

Here is my test screenshot:
[image]

Hope it will help you!

Comment: I've tried using the full path as indicated - but in this case, the command is being run on a vm... The AZ CLI command line is generated by .ssh -it --rm azuresdk/azure-cli-python:latester run -v /Users/bill/.ssh:/root/. Every explanation of the `-f` or `--filename=` attribute suggests that the command references the home directory of the local machine.

Comment: I also do the test in Azure VM with the absolute file path and it works well. I will update the answer with the test screenshot.

Comment: thanks - so just to confirm, the absolute file path you're providing is in a path on your local computer?  That's what it looks like.  If that's the case, I'll rework from the begging and see what I missed...

Comment: Yes, actually say it is on the Azure VM. If you create the VM on your local machine, you should make sure that the absolute path can be found in your VM, not in the host machine.

Comment: @BillArmstrong If the answer is helpful or for more help, please let me know.

Comment: After much testing - there is a local install problem on one computer (the one this question is based on).  I did get this to work on a second company - If I can figure out why I'll post an update.   Thanks.